# Issue with multiple edge selection from vertex in Beldner 2.79

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

I have been working trough a youtube tutorial on making a low poly space ship. After several attempts I can't get the same result as the instructor at time 5:30.
[BLENDER-EP/02 - how to model a low poly spaceship 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NpzJ_0LER4&t=193s)

When selecting the a vertex, I notice not all edges connected to it are highlighted. It would appear I have some how created two vertices in the same point.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I have followed the Tutorial step by step multiple times yet I still get this issue and later on when I UV unwrap, my model is a mess.

Thanks in advance.

Tutorial:
[image: Image from YouTube]

My Model:
[image]

Comment: it's hard to tell how it happened, perhaps you've duplicated your mesh by mistake, anyway you can select all and W > Remove Doubles and it will fix the problem

Comment: @moonboots Thank you so much! Sorted my issue out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell how it happened, perhaps you've duplicated your mesh by mistake, anyway, select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* and it will fix the problem.